# Bamboo Powershell Task fails after first run

Tags: powershell, artifactory, bamboo

I'm completely new to Bamboo, so thank you in advance for the help.

I'm trying to create a Bamboo Run that zips files from a git repo and uploads it to Artifactory.  Currently my build contains 2 tasks - source code checkout and a simple powershell script.  The first time I run it it builds perfectly fine, but without any modifications any consecutive runs fail.

The error I'm getting in the log is the following:

```
Failing task since return code of [powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command /bin/sh /opt/bamboo/agent/temp/OR-J8U-JOB1-4-ScriptBuildTask-539645121146088515.ps1] was -1 while expected 0
```

Replacing the powershell script with empty space does not resolve the issue - only removing the script completely allows the build to succeed, but I cannot reinsert a new script or it will fail.  I read other online questions suggesting that I "merge the user-level PATH environment information in to the system-level PATH" but I cannot find the user-level environment information, my environmental variables section is completely empty.

Comment: I had similar issue. Was not able to find cause/solution. Figured it was more time efficient to re-implement my powershell script with batch.

Answer (score 0):

Like Vlad, I found that it was more efficient to implement my powershell script with batch.